# How come column width can be applied to div but not button?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

This works fine, makes the button `size 4`

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Like</button>
</div>
```

But the following doesn't work:

```
<div>
    <button class="col-xs-4 btn btn-block btn-primary">Like</button>
</div>
```

Which doesn't make sense to me, since I thought the `div` was just a container and its styles/ classes are passed down to its elements.

Comment: When you use Bootstrap you need to understand how the [Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/) works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`col-xs-4` sets the current element's `width` to approximately `33%` and `btn-block` sets the current element's `width` to `100%`.

In this code parent element's `width` (div) is `33%` (because of `col-xs-4`) and child element's width is `100%` (because of `btn-block`).

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Like</button>
</div>
```

In the next code, parent `div`'s display is `block` and its width changes according to what is inside of it. And in child element (Button) it has both `col-xs-4` and `btn-block` classes, but `btn-block` sets `width:100%` and disables `col-xs-4` (width:33%) effect.

```
<div>
    <button class="col-xs-4 btn btn-block btn-primary">Like</button>
</div>
```

If you remove `btn-block` you'll see `col-xs-4` just works fine and sets `width:33%`

```
<div>
    <button class="col-xs-4 btn btn-primary">Like</button>
</div>
```

I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gfLw4b3j/) for you.

Answer (score 2):

In your first example, the div **is** given class "col-xs-4" and will therefore not change in size depending on what is inside the div.

In your second example, the div is **not** given any class and will therefore change in size, depending on what is inside the div.

The reason your second example doesn't work is because of your other classes also changes the button size. By reading the "col-xs-4" class first, the size is overruled by one of the other classes.

Answer (score 0):

you can not apply col-xs-* or any with buttons but if you want to adjust the size of your button the refer this ->
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_buttons.asp

Comment: You **shouldn't**. But you **can**. See fiddle in my answer.

Comment: brother try once remove col-xs-4 from the button then also a button size will not change because of the button class btn btn-block, just try once.